# How to get Duration of each song in playlist in HTML5 Audio Player?

Tags: jquery, html, audio, duration

I'm trying to get duration of each song in playlist. Its giving me NaN. I read that if browser doesn't get enough time to read the audio data then it returns NaN.
So i used `song.onloadedmetadata = duration = song.duration. // song is audio object.`
Its also giving NaN.

If i write `alert("hello");`  before  `song.onloadmetadata = duration = song.duration` then it display duration of song. It means that time browser get enough time to calculate the duration. But i don't want that alert shows on every time i load the page.

Actually I'm loading all songs from XML through for each loop. I'm trying to get duration of each song there. So that i can print song name and its duration on HTML page.
Here is my code please suggest me what should i do.

```
function xmlParser(xml) 
            {
            //alert("Inside XML block");
                $(xml).find("songs").each(function () 
                {
                    $(xml).find("song").each(function(i) 
                    {
                        songurl = $(this).find("music").text();
                        id = $(this).find("music").attr("id");
                        image = $(this).find("image").text();
                        sname = $(this).find("name").text(); 

                        song_name.push(sname);
                        album_image.push(image);                        
                        playlist.push(songurl);


                     //Code to get Each Song Duration in Playlist           

                        song.src = songurl; 


                        song.onloadedmetadata = duration = song.duration;
                            //duration=song.duration;                           

                            var sec= new Number();
                            var min= new Number();
                            sec = Math.floor( duration );    
                            min = Math.floor( sec / 60 );
                            min = min >= 10 ? min : '0' + min;    
                            sec = Math.floor( sec % 60 );
                            sec = sec >= 10 ? sec : '0' + sec;

                        //code For Each song duration Ends Here

                        $("#SongsList" ).append('<li id="'+id+'"> <a href="#" id="'+id+'">' +sname+  ' </a> <h6 style="color:#74dad5; font-family:verdana; padding-left:279px;">'+min+' : '+sec+' </h6></li> ');

                    });                 



                });
            }
```

Please tell me where i'm wrong and provide me code so that i can get the duration inside that loop and print it on my page.

Comment: Do you control the audio files, or do they come from another site? If you control the files, then preprocessing would be in order. What format are the files? .mp3? .m4a? .ogg? A mix?

Comment: @MultimediaMike  I'm making Audio Player Demo and yeah I'm controlling Sound and it is of MP3 format. I didn't understand about preprocessing order. Please explain

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set a callback to song.onloadedmetadata, and then get duration in this callback function.

```
song.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  dump('duration onloadeddata = ' + song.duration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple workaround:

load the song durations once the user scrolls using:

`$(document).scroll(function() { //load song durations}`

Then set the page to automatically scroll onload using

`$(window).load(function() {  document.getElementById( 'any_id' ).scrollIntoView() })`